# Using ABCalendarPicker

Tags: ios6, abaddressbook

I am having trouble with ABCalendarPicker.  Can someone please explain why the below screenshot is coming out this way?  I have added the bundle and the .a library as build resources.  I have also built the ABCalendarPicker project prior to running.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ABCalendarPicker` component does not support Autolayout. Just disable Autolayout or help to improve component...